# How to find the closest stop point PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, nearest-neighbor

I have Point geometries created from lat,lon
I loaded all the 10,000 stops in a certain city using gtfs

i would like to query my db to find the closest stop reference to my point.

the staypoint table is

```
    CREATE TABLE stay_points
    (
        ad_id uuid NOT NULL,
        latitude numeric NOT NULL,
        longitude numeric NOT NULL,
        start_utc_timestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
        end_utc_timestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
        cluster_id numeric NOT NULL,
        radius numeric NOT NULL,
        geom geometry(Point,4326)
    )
    WITH (
        OIDS = FALSE
    )
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

and the stop table is :

```
    CREATE TABLE public.stops
(
    stop_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    stop_lon real NOT NULL,
    stop_lat real NOT NULL,
    stop_desc text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    stop_code text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    agency integer,
    zone_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    stop_url text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    location_type numeric,
    parent_station text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    stop_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

My current solution involves pandas and scipy kdtree and thought there must be a better way

Answer (score 1):

First, you should add a geometry(point, 4326) field to your stops table, since you started with the other table as a geometry.

```
ALTER TABLE public.stops ADD COLUMN geom geometry(POINT,4326);
UPDATE public.stops SET geom =  ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(stop_lon, stop_lat),4326);
```

Make sure to have an index on the fields, for this case you better need a geography index:

```
CREATE INDEX stay_points_geog_idx ON public.stay_points USING GIST(cast(geom as geography));
CREATE INDEX stops_geog_idx ON public.stops USING GIST(cast(geom as geography));
```

Analyze your tables, to be sure that the planner knows about your indexes:

```
ANALYZE public.stops;
ANALYZE public.stay_points;
```

Now you can request the nearest-neighbor for your points, using postgis [tool made for that](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) (<->) and a CROSS JOIN LATERAL (don't forget to cast in geography):

```
SELECT 
    stops.*,
    stay_points.*
FROM 
    stay_points
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
        (
            SELECT
                *,
                ST_Distance(geography(stay_points.geom), geography(stops.geom)) as distance
            FROM stops
            ORDER BY geography(stay_points.geom) <-> geography(stops.geom)
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS stops;
```

(untested code, but this should be the idea)

Comment: Technically, you could do a LEFT JOIN LATERAL instead but the CROSS JOIN is common in this case because with that you can change the LIMIT 1 to a LIMIT10 for example to have for each stay_point the 10 nearest neighbors (and with a CROSS you will end up with 10 lines by stay_points in your result, whereas with the lateral still only the closest)